# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm doing a  notes app in React Native, but this error shows up all the time. Tried debugging with chatGPT, and nothing change.

This is the code block where the error comes from.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDataContext } from './DataProvider';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Pressable, Alert } from 'react-native';
import NotesContainer from './NotesContainer';
import EditNotes from './EditNotes';


export default function Notes() {
  const { noteItems, setNoteItems } = useDataContext;
  
  const [editingNoteIndex, setEditingNoteIndex] = useState(-1);

  const completeNote = (index) => {
    // Show a confirmation dialog
    Alert.alert(
        'Delete Note',
        'Are you sure you want to delete this note?',
        [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            style: 'cancel',
          },
          {
            text: 'Delete',
            style: 'destructive',
            onPress: () => {
              // If the user confirms, delete the note
              let itemsCopy = [...noteItems];
              itemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
              setNoteItems(itemsCopy);
            },
            textStyles: styles.deleteButton,
          },
        ],
        { cancelable: true }
    );
  }

  const handleSaveEdit = (editedNote, index) => {
    const updatedNotes = [...noteItems];
    updatedNotes[index] = editedNote;
    setNoteItems(updatedNotes);
    stopEditing();
  };

  const handleCancelEdit = () => {
      stopEditing();
  };

  const stopEditing = () => {
    setEditingNoteIndex(-1);
  };

  return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.container}>
          {noteItems.map((item, index) => (
            item && item.title ? ( // Check if 'item' exists and has a 'title' property
              <Pressable
                key={index}
                onPress={() => completeNote(index)}
              >
                {editingNoteIndex === index ? 
                  (
                    <EditNotes
                      note={item} // Pass the item to the EditNotes component
                      onSave={(editedNote) => handleSaveEdit(editedNote, index)}
                      onCancel={() => handleCancelEdit()}
                    />
                  ) : 
                  (
                    <NotesContainer
                      title={item.title}
                      text={item.text}
                      index={index}
                      noteItems={noteItems}
                      onSaveEdit={handleSaveEdit}
                      stopEditing={stopEditing}
                    />
                  )
                }
              </Pressable>
            ) : null
          ))}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
  )
}
```

I'm using useContext to provide the array 'noteItems', so I can use it in other components too.

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const DataContext = createContext();

const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [noteItems, setNoteItems] = useState([]);
    const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);
    const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

    const handleAddNote = (newNote) => {
        setNoteItems([...noteItems, newNote]);
    }

    return (
        <DataContext.Provider value={{ noteItems, setNoteItems, handleAddNote, taskItems, setTaskItems }}>
            {children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useDataContext = () => useContext(DataContext);
export default DataProvider;
```

These are the other components:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Pressable, Modal } from 'react-native';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import EditNotes from './EditNotes';


export default function NotesContainer(props) {

    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
    const { title, text, index, onSaveEdit } = props;
    const [editedNote, setEditedNote] = useState({ title, text });

    const handleSaveEdit = (editedNote) => {
        onSaveEdit(editedNote, index);
        setIsEditing(false);
    };

    return (
        <View>
            {isEditing ? (
                <Modal>
                    <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                        <EditNotes
                            note={{ title, text }}
                            onSave={handleSaveEdit}
                            onCancel={() => setIsEditing(false)}
                        />
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            ) : (
                <View style={styles.notesContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.title} ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1}>{title}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.text} ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={4}>{text}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.icon}>
                        <Pressable onPress={() => setIsEditing(true)}>
                            <Icon
                                name="create-outline"
                                size={40}
                            />
                        </Pressable>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

```
import React, { useState , useContext} from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { useDataContext } from './DataProvider';

export default function CreateNotes() {
    const { noteItems, setNoteItems, handleAddNote } = useDataContext;

    const [noteTitle, setNoteTitle] = useState('');
    const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState('');

    const addNote = () => {
        const newNote = {
            title: noteTitle,
            text: noteText,
        };
        handleAddNote(newNote);
        setNoteTitle(''); // Clear the input fields
        setNoteText('');
    }
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           <ScrollView style={styles.inputArea}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputTitle}
                    value={noteTitle}
                    onChangeText={title => setNoteTitle(title)}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    multiline={true}
                    value={noteText}
                    keyboardType='default'
                    onChangeText={text => setNoteText(text)}
                />
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Pressable onPress={() => addNote()}> 
                    <Icon
                        name={"bookmark"}
                        //color="#87CEFA"
                        size={40}
                    />
                </Pressable>
            </View> 
        </View>
        
    )
}
```

```
import React, { useState , useContext} from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Pressable, Modal } from 'react-native';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import Notes from './Notes';

export default function EditNotes({ note, onSave, onCancel }) {

    const [editedNote, setEditedNote] = useState({
        title: note.title || '', // Set a default empty string or use note's title if available
        text: note.text || '',   // Set a default empty string or use note's text if available
    });
  
    const handleSave = () => {
      onSave(editedNote);
    };
  
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputTitle}
                    value={editedNote.title}
                    onChangeText={(title) => setEditedNote({ ...editedNote, title })}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    multiline={true}
                    value={editedNote.text}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setEditedNote({ ...editedNote, text })}
                />
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Pressable style={styles.icon} onPress={handleSave}>
                    <Icon
                        name={"checkmark-outline"}
                        //color="#87CEFA"
                        size={50}
                    />
                </Pressable>
                <Pressable style={styles.icon} onPress={onCancel}>
                    <Icon
                        name={"close-circle-outline"}
                        //color="#87CEFA"
                        size={50}
                    />
                </Pressable>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: _`= useDataContext;`_  shouldn't you be calling this function? ie `useDataContext()`

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you som much.

Answer (score -1):

I saw 2 issues in your code.

1. I think it is just a typo in this example, but you have to call the hook `useDataContext()`. as I can see, you didn't do it.
2. You also did not use the `DataProvider` component. you have to use the context provider to give it a value. it is also a good practice to define a default value for cases where the Provider's value has not been set yet:

```js
const MyContext = createContext({ 
    noteItems: [],
    setNoteItems: () => {},
    handleAddNote: () => {},
    taskItems: [],
    setTaskItems: () => {},
})
```

Comment: It was a typo problem. So many hours to this. haha'
Thank you so much!